# How to handle unzipping ZipFile with paths that are too long/duplicate

Tags: c#, zip, dotnetzip

When unzipping files in Windows, I'll occasionally have problems with paths

1. that are too long for Windows (but okay in the original OS that created the file).
2. that are "duplicate" due to case-insensitivity

Using DotNetZip, the `ZipFile.Read(path)` call will crap out whenever reading zip files with one of these problems.  Which means I can't even try filtering it out.

```
using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(path))
{
    ...
}
```

What is the best way to handle reading those sort of files?

*Updated:*

Example zip from here:
https://github.com/MonoReports/MonoReports/zipball/master

Duplicates:
https://github.com/MonoReports/MonoReports/tree/master/src/MonoReports.Model/DataSourceType.cs
https://github.com/MonoReports/MonoReports/tree/master/src/MonoReports.Model/DatasourceType.cs

Here is more detail on the exception:

> Ionic.Zip.ZipException: Cannot read that as a ZipFile
>   ---> System.ArgumentException: An > item with the same key has already been added.
>     at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
>     at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
>
>     at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
>     at Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.ReadCentralDirectory(ZipFile zf)
>     at Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.ReadIntoInstance(ZipFile zf)

**Resolution:**

Based on @Cheeso's suggestion, I can read everything from the stream, those avoiding duplicates, and path issues:

```
//using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(path))
using (ZipInputStream stream = new ZipInputStream(path))
{
    ZipEntry e;
    while( (e = stream.GetNextEntry()) != null )
    //foreach( ZipEntry e in zip)
    {
        if (e.FileName.ToLower().EndsWith(".cs") ||
            e.FileName.ToLower().EndsWith(".xaml"))
        {
            //var ms = new MemoryStream();
            //e.Extract(ms);
            var sr = new StreamReader(stream);
            {
                //ms.Position = 0;
                CodeFiles.Add(new CodeFile() { Content = sr.ReadToEnd(), FileName = e.FileName });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the file .zip or .gz?

Comment: .zip (specifically from github zipfile downloads)

Comment: Can you show the error? Is it the pathname inside the file? Is it the target file location that's too long?

Comment: I updated the question to be more general: both duplicate files and long paths are a problem and include examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read it with `ZipInputStream`.

The `ZipFile` class keeps a collection using the filename as the index. Duplicate filenames breaks that model.

But you can use the `ZipInputStream` to read in your `ZipFile`. There is no collection or index in that case.

Answer (score 9):

For the `PathTooLongException` problem, I found that you can't use [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/). Instead, what I did was invoke the [command-line version of 7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/a/7za920.zip); that works wonders.

```
public static void Extract(string zipPath, string extractPath)
{
    try
    {
        ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
            FileName = Path.GetFullPath(@"7za.exe"),
            Arguments = "x \"" + zipPath + "\" -o\"" + extractPath + "\""
        };
        Process process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
        process.WaitForExit();
        if (process.ExitCode != 0) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error extracting {0}.", extractPath);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error extracting {0}: {1}", extractPath, e.Message);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is actually the easiest solution I found.  At the time of this comment, it might be helpful to know that the 7za.exe is in the 7-zip downloads with "7-zip extra: ...."  in the description. (http://www.7-zip.org/download.html)

Comment: The `Arguments` line is incorrect; it should be `Arguments = "x \"" + zipPath + "\" -o \"" + extractPath + "\""` (note no space between the **o** switch and `extractPath`.

Comment: Thanks @sigil, according to [this](http://superuser.com/questions/95902/7-zip-and-unzipping-from-command-line) you are correct, I updated my answer.

Comment: Good answer. Also to avoid for the process to stop with prompt about overriding existing you can add `-y` to the arguments