# How can I store a directory structure inside a resource?

Tags: c#, .net, embedded-resource

I am writing a plugin for a .NET based CMS and I want to unpack a tree of javascript, CSS and image files when it runs for the first time. Because I want to ship just a single dll, I was going to zip up those directories and store them as a resource. Then when the plugin runs, it checks to see if the requisite files exist, and if not, it will unpack them.

I know resources are "flat", in that you can't set up a directory structure, so some form of packing is the only way I can see to do it.

**The question is**, firstly, is this an acceptable thing to do and secondly, are there any libraries built into .NET to allow me to do this? I am thinking I may have to use GZip rather than Zip if I want to use built-ins, but is there a preferred way to do what I'm trying to achieve?

---

Just to add something to the question - I'm aware that a common scheme is to use .tar.gz, which I'm currently doing at the moment. But for some reason this strikes me as sub-optimal, since I have to import external libraries in order to work like this. I figured this might be a common enough thing to do that there'd be a one or two-liner way to do it natively.

Comment: "Answers in the form of links to articles are fine"... no, they are not :-) Answers on Stack Overflow should always be more than a link.

Comment: True. I was being nice because I figured my question might have been irritatingly fundamental - just I haven't worked with resources in this way before. - There we go, edited :)

Comment: not really an answer but a hint in a similar post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10677405/how-to-handle-unzipping-zipfile-with-paths-that-are-too-long-duplicate

Comment: Make sure you have write access to file system at runtime (If it  would be me your code will not not have write access to images/css locations).

Comment: Thanks for the tip Alexei. Yes, my plugin writes to the Assets directory of the CMS, which is where you put files like the ones I intend to extract.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of ways to package and compress groups of files shipped with .net http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.aspx (release in .net 3.0 i think) and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.aspx (new in .Net 4.5)

There are also a couple of free open source libraries you can use (Sharp Zip Lib: http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/ and DotNetZip lib http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/).  There are probably others.  I've used them both as well as the Packaging apis.  I favor the DotNetZip for its ease of use, but you can be productive with any of them pretty quickly.

It makes sense to compress the resources - that's smart use of space - but your resources don't have to directly map to how/where you are going to extract them (since you write the code to extract and write the resources you can store them flat if it makes more sense).

Comment: Thanks Jason, I'm actually looking at sharpziplib at the moment :). System.IO.Packaging might be just what I'm looking for also. I'll try it out and let you know how I go.

Comment: I currently use the System.IO.Packaging on a project and it works good enough.  The new .net 4.5 stuff looks even better but I can't upgrade to it yet.  Good luck.